# Python dictionary to store socket objects

Tags: python

Can we store socket objects in a Python dictionary. 
I want to create a socket, store socket object, do some stuff and then read from the socket(search from dictionary to get socketobject).

Comment: You can store any python object as a value in a dict. (But only hashable objects can be used as keys.)

Answer (score 10):

Yes:

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket()
>>> d = {"key" : s}
>>> d
{'key': <socket._socketobject object at 0x00CEB5A8>}
```

Comment: Can we compare these socket objects for equality like:
if sokObj1 == sokObj2:
    #Do some operation

Comment: Which socket objects do you mean, exactly? Obviously if you put `s` into `d` with key "key", then `d["key"]` will return the exact same object `s` which you put in.